# Problema con el MySQL del XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

He tenido un problema con el XAMPP, no carga el MySQL

> 12:00:54 a.m.  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 12:00:54 a.m.  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing
>   dependencies,   12:00:54 a.m.  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash,
>   or a shutdown by another method.
>
> 12:00:54 a.m.  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and
>   check
>
> 12:00:54 a.m.  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 12:00:54 a.m.  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 12:00:54 a.m.  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums

¿qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: Por lo que leo, debes verificar en que puerto estas levantando el MySql ya que lo tienes bloqueado.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Puede que le interese leer esto http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour . Puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada o puesta en espera, no se lo tome a mal. Para mas información vea http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions . Saludos

Comment: Prueba de correr xamp con permisos de administrador

Comment: Yo intenté seguir varios tutos pero ninguno me funciona, simplemente es porque el socket mysqld no inicia. Solucioné este inconveniente volviendo a instalar XAMPP

Answer (score 2):

Este error se puede llegar a presentar por dos cosas.

#### Directorio de Instalación

El directorio es diferente a la raíz establecida por el propio paquete de instalación, Xampp pre-configura algunas cosas utilizando una ruta de especifica. Instala nuevamente Xampp en la raiz de tu disco principal.

#### Puertos en Uso

Los puertos que utiliza por defecto el servidor Apache y MySQL (80 y 443) están siendo utilizados por otras aplicaciones ya activas en tu equipo. Verifica que estas se encuentren libres y en dado caso que no puedas detener los procesos modifica los archivos de configuración.

> **httpd.conf** ubicado en"C:\Xammp\Apache\Conf" y sustituir ServerName
>   localhost:80 por ServerName localhost:8080. Listen 80 por Listen 8080.

y

> **httpd-ssl.conf** ubicado en "C:\Xammp\Apache\Conf\Extra" y sustituir:
>    por .
>   ServerName localhost:443 por ServerName localhost:4430. Listen 443 por
>   Listen 4430.